# Using Code signing certificate PFX on a different PC?

Tags: pfx

I've gone thru the steps to get a Code Signing Certificate from GoDaddy.  Did the entire process and export to a PFX which I then use in Visual Studio 2015 for my solutions/projects.  All good so far, no issues.

Our solutions and projects are under TFS source control.  I check-in my solution/projects.  A co-worker on a separate PC "gets latest" and she adds the same PFX file I used to her VS 2015 project/solutions.

However, when my co-worker compiles her projects/solutions she gets a: 
"Xap packaging failed.  Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

She's tried everything (clean, rebuild, etc. etc.) and still gets the same error.  The only way she can compile is if she unchecks the "Sign the Xap File" in the project properties/Signing (basically not using the PFX file).

The PFX file shows up correctly in the Project propertiers/signing window but still get the above compile error?

Any suggestions?

Rob.